# Office 365: Connecting to Office Online 365 service using Power Shell Script issue

Tags: c#, sharepoint, powershell, powershell-cmdlet

I have Windows Server 2008 R2 machine and it has Power Shell v1.0. I wanted to connect to MS 365 online service using Power Shell with C#. I have installed Office 365 cmdlets and Microsoft Online Services Sign-In Assistant. ( Ref: http://onlinehelp.microsoft.com/en-us/office365-enterprises/hh124998.aspx#BKMK_install  )

My script is:

```
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString "xxxxx" -AsPlainText –Force

$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PsCredential("xxxx@xxxx.onmicrosoft.com",$password)

$cred = Get-Credential -cred $credential

Import-Module MSOnline

Connect-Msolservice -cred $cred
```

I can successfully run this script in the Power Shell Command window. But I have problem running this script in c# application.

Here is my c# code:

```
  public void RunScript()
    {
        StringBuilder ss = new StringBuilder();
        ss.AppendLine("$password = ConvertTo-SecureString \"" + pwd + "\" -AsPlainText –Force");
        ss.AppendLine("$credential = New-Object  System.Management.Automation.PsCredential(\"" + userName + "\",$password)");
        ss.AppendLine("$cred = Get-Credential -cred $credential");
        ss.AppendLine("Import-Module MSOnline");
        ss.AppendLine("Connect-Msolservice -cred $cred");

        using (Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace())
        {
            Collection<PSObject> results = null;
            try
            {
                runspace.Open();
                Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
                pipeline.Commands.AddScript(ss.toString());

                results = pipeline.Invoke();
            }
            finally
            {
                runspace.Close();
            }                
        }
    }
```

I get the following exception:

The term 'Connect-Msolservice' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Is there anything missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
InitialSessionState iss = InitialSessionState.CreateDefault();
iss.ImportPSModule(new string[] { "MSOnline" });

using (Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(iss))
{
// blah
}
```

Comment: Well thanks for the comment. I will try with your suggestion also. However, I have found the reason why it didn't recognize the "Connect-Msolservice" command. The reason was simple. I had created a console application whose Platform target is x86 while my dev machine is Microsoft Server 2008 64bit where I have installed MS Online Service module (64bits). By changing the Platform target to any cpu solve the issue.

Comment: Hi David,I tried with the above solution but the same result (no success). 
BTW. It seems that cmdlets of MS Online service module (64bits) has to be executed/run from the 64bits Process/application. This is what I have experienced. Please share if you have any idea on this.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, Prakash. I ran into the same issue.

Comment: I was having problems, then, on my 64-bit Windows 10 machine, in Project properties, I set Build -> Platform Target to x64 and the script imported the module successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you have installed following things:

```
 1. SharePoint Online Management Shell
 2. Microsoft Online Services Sign-In Assistant version 7.0 or greater version
 3. Windows Azure Active Directory Module
```